# comparision with rank one projection

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $P$ is a rank one projection in $B(H)$,if we have $T\in B(H)$ such that $0\leq T\leq P$,does the following conclusion hold:
There exists $\alpha \geq 0$ such that $T=\alpha P.$

Comment: For any $x\in H$ you have $\langle x ,(P-T) x\rangle = \langle x, Px\rangle - \langle x, Tx\rangle ≥0$. Use self-adjointness and positivity of $T$ to see that $T$ is zero on $\mathrm{im}(P)^\perp$. Can you see how to continue?